# to which thread gdb connects by default

Tags: gdb

If I have some multithreaded process and want to trace it with `gdb` using `attach` command, to which thread it will connect (e.g. current running or main)? I know that I can discover it with `info threads` but I want to know which thread it will choose by default.

Answer (score 1):

For Linux, all of the threads are stopped by the `ptrace` command when gdb attaches.

It has been my experience that gdb defaults to the main thread for C/C++ applications. If you attach to a process and do a 'bt' it will list the stack for 'main'.

Information is available for all threads however.  gdb can look at the thread(s) information in the `/proc` filesystem.  The proc contains information about each thread in the `tasks` area. Details about the stack address is located in the `stat` file as well as the `maps` file.  Details are also available regarding the register values for each thread.

Along the lines of your question, I've often wondered why stepping through a multithreaded application will cause gdb to jump from thread to thread. I think that gdb is still at the mercy of the kernel scheduler so that a step on a thread may lead to a different thread getting the CPU resource and a breakpoint being triggered.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that it always connected to the main thread but I wonder if there is some official documentation that guarantees that.

Comment: About stepping from thread to thread, gdb's documentation have some notes about it here: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_39.html#SEC40  _In particular, GDB cannot single-step all threads in lockstep. Since thread scheduling is up to your debugging target's operating system (not controlled by GDB), other threads may execute more than one statement while the current thread completes a single step. Moreover, in general other threads stop in the middle of a statement, rather than at a clean statement boundary, when the program stops._

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, where thread ids exist in the same space as process ids, it appears you can run `gdb -p tid` to attach to the thread with given `tid` and its owning process, without knowing the `pid`. Because the main thread of a process has `tid == pid`, it makes sense that running `gdb -p pid` connects to the main thread.

Example code that connects gdb to the currently executing thread, e.g. for generating a pretty stack trace: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/pull/11150